# Magic number in resource loading routine

Tags: windows, x86-64, winapi

I'm practicing windows disassembly on x64 notepad.exe

I've managed to find buffer allocation and string resources load.
But after that follows code, which I can't fully understand:
rbx = 0, rdx = 0 before this part

```
            mov     r9, cs:str_res_guid_18 ;  dq 12h
            lea     rcx, some_data         ;  some address
            mov     edx, 28h
            sub     r9, rcx        
            mov     r8, rdx

loc_100003150: 
            lea     rax, [r8+7FFFFFD6h]    ; what is this number?
            cmp     rax, rbp
            jz      short loc_100003173
            movzx   eax, word ptr [rcx+r9] ; str_res_guid_18
            cmp     ax, bp
            jz      short loc_100003173
            mov     [rcx], ax
            add     rcx, 2
            sub     r8, 1
            jnz     short loc_100003150

loc_100003173: 
            cmp     r8, rbp
            jz      loc_1000058A0
```

What does 7FFFFFD6h stands for? And why is it compared against null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an optimized wchar_t string copy. The compiler took advantage of the fact that there is a fixed offset between source and destination. Ignoring the  lea  check, the assembly could be represented by this pseudocode:

```
wchar_t *dst = &some_data; //rcx
wchar_t *src = ?; //r9
delta = src-dst; //r9 =r9-dst
maxc = 0x28; //r8

loop:
 wchar_t ch = dst[delta]; (dst+(src-dst) = src, so ch=src[i];)
 if ( ch==0 ) break;
 *dst = ch;
 dst++;
 maxc--;
 if ( maxc!=0 ) goto loop;
```

Now let's look at the mysterious `lea`. First thing you need to remember that it's basically just a fancy `mov`, and the operands are not necessarily addresses.

so let's take `lea     rax, [r8+7FFFFFD6h]` and do some math:

```
rax = r8+0x7FFFFFD6
```

multiply both sides by 2:

```
2*rax = 2*r8+0xFFFFFFAC
```

treat number as signed:

```
2*rax = 2*r8-0x54
```

now divide:

```
rax = r8 - 0x2a
```

so testing rax==0 is the same as r8==0x2a. Possibly the code is checking that number of characters to copy is not greater than the buffer size.

Comment: Thanks Igor, that seems to be the case and it all fits. However, can you clarify, why is there a multiplication in lea.

Comment: @VladFedyaev there is no multiplication, it’s been factored out by the compiler. basically, 0x7FFFFFD6 is 0xFFFFFFAC divided by two without sign extension. I multiplied the equation so it’s easier to see where 0x2A is coming from.

Comment: see also a similar trick here: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/6272

Answer (score 0):

ignore the first part: 7FF..FF is a sequence of 1's
The interesting part is the D6 which equals 1101 0110, or 214 in decimal.
So it check's whether a couple of bytes after the addrress in R8 is a Zero

Also, have a look at section OPERATING SYSTEMS here:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/introduction-to-x64-assembly